# Parsing JSON in objective C and is there anything like the swifty Json alternative in Objective C. If not Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, google-books

I am new to Objective C. I was trying to parse Google books API data.this is a sample API.

```
{  
"kind":"books#volumes",
"totalItems":1,
"items":[  
   {  
      "kind":"books#volume",
      "id":"pDsFCAAAQBAJ",
      "etag":"OVqN1FTxGJg",
     "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/pDsFCAAAQBAJ",
     "volumeInfo":{  
        "title":"Code Complete",
        "authors":[  
           "Steve McConnell"
        ],
        "publisher":"Pearson Education",
        "publishedDate":"2004",
        "description":"Features the best practices in the art and science of constructing software--topics include design, applying good techniques to construction, eliminating errors, planning, managing construction activities, and relating personal character to superior software. Original. (Intermediate)",
        "industryIdentifiers":[  
           {  
              "type":"ISBN_13",
              "identifier":"9780735619678"
           },
           {  
              "type":"ISBN_10",
              "identifier":"0735619670"
           }
        ],
        "readingModes":{  
           "text":false,
           "image":true
        },
        "pageCount":914,
        "printType":"BOOK",
        "categories":[  
           "Computers"
        ],
        "averageRating":4.5,
        "ratingsCount":11,
        "maturityRating":"NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging":false,
        "contentVersion":"preview-1.0.0",
        "imageLinks":{  
           "smallThumbnail":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=pDsFCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
           "thumbnail":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=pDsFCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "language":"en",
        "previewLink":"http://books.google.com/books?id=pDsFCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:0735619670&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
        "infoLink":"http://books.google.com/books?id=pDsFCAAAQBAJ&dq=isbn:0735619670&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "canonicalVolumeLink":"https://books.google.com/books/about/Code_Complete.html?hl=&id=pDsFCAAAQBAJ"
     },
     "saleInfo":{  
        "country":"US",
        "saleability":"NOT_FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook":false
     },
     "accessInfo":{  
        "country":"US",
        "viewability":"PARTIAL",
        "embeddable":true,
        "publicDomain":false,
        "textToSpeechPermission":"ALLOWED_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY",
        "epub":{  
           "isAvailable":false
        },
        "pdf":{  
           "isAvailable":false
        },
        "webReaderLink":"http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=pDsFCAAAQBAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api",
        "accessViewStatus":"SAMPLE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed":false
     },
     "searchInfo":{  
        "textSnippet":"Features the best practices in the art and science of constructing software--topics include design, applying good techniques to construction, eliminating errors, planning, managing construction activities, and relating personal character to ..."
     }
  }
]
}
```

I want to parse title, author, thumbnail and description.How can I do it?? is there a library I can use in objective c to do this.?

If no library is present or if it's not preferred .... why is that?

One of the reasons that I could think of is that it might be easier than swift. But then why did Apple implement the same for swift?

Comment: what you have done so far. please share your code

Comment: NSJSONSerialization works correctly. It's just NSDictionaries, NSArray, NSString and NSNumber. Nothing too complicate to iterate.

Comment: There is no pressure to have a special lib in Objective-C, because it is objective-C-ish to deal with generic types. However, I think that you are asking for an event-driven lib: https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad what do u mean??

Comment: I. e. if you want to access the content, you can use kvc or subscription without having a concrete type reading the JSON document. If you have a JSON object, you simply do not have to care whether it is an instance of an object type (class) of your app or a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *MainDict =.....;  //it contain your JSON responce
     NSLog(@"str : %@",MainDict);

     NSDictionary * ItemDict = [MainDict valueForKey:@"items"]; //It create Item dictionary

    //To get title
    NSDictionary * TitleDict = [ItemDict valueForKey:@"volumeInfo"];
    NSString * TitleStr = [TitleDict valueForKey:@"title"];             //You get title from here

    //Author are in Array format so you can create an NSArray for author name
    NSArray * AuthornameArray = [TitleDict valueForKey:@"authors"];     //you get Authors

    //Description
    NSString * DescriptionString = [ItemDict valueForKey:@"description"];

    //Thumbnail
    NSDictionary * imageLinksDict = [ItemDict valueForKey:@"imageLinks"];
    NSString * ThumbnailStr = [imageLinksDict valueForKey:@"thumbnail"];        //Your thumbnail is here
```

You can Use `NSLog` to check correct response

Comment: One of the reasons that I could think of is that it might be easier than swift. But then y did apple implement the same for swift?

Comment: you will get your answer here https://mlsdev.com/blog/51-7-advantages-of-using-swift-over-objective-c

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you need KVC. Can you? Use `objectForKey` or modern key subscription like `imageLinksDict[@"thumbnail"]`. And variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: it is just only a reference answer so that @ashin get some help to solve his issues

Comment: @vadian can you give me an example??what is KVC?

Comment: KVC is [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KeyValueCoding.html). It's used to access properties by key or key paths. But it's the wrong way to get a single value from a dictionary

Comment: @vadian can u give me an example of right way?? thanks!